# When is $32x+32$ a square number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

I am trying to find out for what values for $x$ does the function $f(x)=32x+32$ return a square number? I found that this is the case for at least: $x \in \{64,1600,53824,1827904,62094400,2109381184\}$ but I can't see a pattern in those numbers.

Is there a formula which generates these values for $x$ instead of simply trying a lot of values?

Comment: I'm not sure about a formula, but didn't you miss one?  If $x = 31$, then $32(31) + 32 = (32)(32)$ which is a square.

Comment: @randomgirl deleted her answer, but I thought it was useful.  Basically she said that since $32 = 2^{5}$, then $32x + 32 = 2^{5}(x + 1)$.  So if $x + 1 = 2^{2k + 1}$ for any integer $k \geq 0$, then $2^{5}(x + 1)$ will be a perfect square.  But actually $x + 1$ could equal infinitely many possibilities, since we could have $x + 1 = 2a^{2}$ for any integer $a$, or $x + 1 = 2a^{2k}b^{2j}c^{2n}$ for any integers $a,b,c$ and integers $k, j, n \geq 0$ (and so on).  This should at least convince you that there are **infinitely** many solutions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

$$32(x + 1) = y^2 \implies 32 \mid y^2 \implies 4 \mid y$$ so let $y = 4z$. $$2(x+1) = z^2 \implies 2 \mid z$$ so let $z = 2w$ $$x + 1 = 2w^2 $$ so given any $w$ we can solve for $x$.

So the set of solutions is
$$\{(2w^2 - 1, 8w) \mid w \in \Bbb Z\}$$

Comment: @user46944 Please see my last edit.

Comment: You need to exclude $w=0$, don't you?

Comment: @ClementC. If you want. I'm listing all solutions over the integers.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Sorry about that.

Comment: In fact, $32|y^2$ already implies $8|y$ the two consequtive steps aren't necessary.

Comment: what does the $8w$ in the last line mean? And I assume that $4|y$ means that $y$ is divisible by $4$?

Comment: @HéctorvandenBoorn $4 \mid y$ means $4$ divides $y$, so the other way round.

Comment: @user109899 Thanks! Edited.

Comment: Excellent answer! thanks

Comment: @user3491648 that's not the other way around, "y is divisible by 4" and "4 divides y" mean the same thing.

Comment: Perhaps I'm an Amateur, but it's not that obvious, at least to me, that $(32 \mid y^2) \implies (8 \mid y)$, versus, $(32 \mid y^2) \implies (4 \mid y)$, or even, $(32 \mid y^2) \implies (2 \mid y)$.  Yet I see that

Comment: Yet I see that if, $u \cdot 2^5=y^2$ then $$u=2^{2n+1} \cdot 3^{\alpha_2} \cdot 5^{\alpha_3} \cdot \cdots$$ and $$y=+(u \cdot 2^5)^{1/2}$$ implies that the min exponent of $2$ for $y$ would be $$min \left(\frac{2n+1}{2} + \frac{5}{2} \right)$$ or $$ min \left( n+3\right)$$ which is 3 allowing n=0

Comment: @AmateurMathGuy See the earlier edits

Answer (score 3):

The answer by user3491648 gives a complete characterization of the full set of values $x$ for which $32x+32$ is a square numbers.  This is really just an observation on the set of values

$$\{64,1600,53824,1827904,62094400,2109381184\}$$

reported by the OP.

These are not actually values that $x$ takes on.  (As user3491648 finds, it requires on *odd* value of $x$ to make $32x+32$ a square.)  Rather, these seem to be the square values that correspond to values of $x$ that are themselves squares, namely of the following values:

$$\{1,7,41,239,1393,8119\}$$

For example, $32\cdot239^2+32=1827904$.  It's unclear why these values are being singled out, but they do seem to obey a two-term recursion, namely

$$a_{n+1}=6a_n-a_{n-1}$$

For example, $1393=6\cdot239-41$.

Comment: Great observation! I was actually trying to find values for x where (x*x)-1 mod 8 == 0 and where 32*x*x+32 is a square

Answer (score -2):

Solution for x such that 32x+32 is a square as follows:
 For integral solution,  x= (n2 -2)/2 such that x is in Natural number.(n is in natural number)