# When is $8x^2-4$ a square number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

I asked an earlier question on when $32x+32$ is a square number ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1326562/when-is-32x32-a-square-number#1326568)) and I got a very clear answer.

Now I am looking to solve for which $x$ the equation $8x^2-4$ results in a square number. When I am trying to solve it I get: $y^2=4(2x^2-1)$ so if we put $y=2w$ then $2x^2-1 = w^2$ and therefore $x=\sqrt{\frac{w^2+1}{2}}$ which is correct.

Only now I need to check when $\frac{w^2-1}{2}$ is a square which goes on recursively. I am looking for **Integer** solutions for $x$ and $w$. How can I solve this?

Comment: You get $w^2 - 2x^2 = -1$. That is a negative Pell equation.

Comment: If it may help, The values of $x$ that results in squared value begin with the series $x=1, 5, 29, 169, 985, 5741, 33461, 195025$. These x values look like they are generated from https://oeis.org/A001653

Comment: you mean (w^2+1)/2 is a square. If so w=5 and w=41 are two values.

Comment: You can find the values of $x$ using:

$x = \frac{7 + 5 \sqrt{2}}{2 \sqrt{2}} \Big( 3 + 2 \sqrt{2} \Big)^{n-1}
-\frac{7 - 5 \sqrt{2}}{2 \sqrt{2}}   \Big( 3 - 2 \sqrt{2} \Big)^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 7):

Given the equation
$$
2 n^2 - 1 = ( m - n )^2.
$$

From this we can write
$$
2 m n = m^2 - n^2 + 1.
$$

Let
$$
x = m^2 - n^2, y = 2 m n, z = m^2 + n^2 \Rightarrow x^2 + y^2 = z^2.
$$

But
$$
y = x + 1,
$$

so we obtain
$$
x^2 + ( x + 1 )^2 = z^2,
$$

which can be written as
$$
2 z^2 - 1 = ( 2 x + 1 )^2,
$$

or
$$
2 \big( \underbrace{m^2 + n^2}_{n'} \big)^2 - 1 = \big( \underbrace{ 2 \big[ m^2 - n^2 \big] + 1 }_{m'-n'} \big)^2.
$$

So starting with
$$
\big( m, n \big)
$$

we can "generate" the next pair $(m',n')$ using
$$
\big( m', n' \big) = \big( 3 m^2 - n^2 + 1, m^2 + n^2 \big).
$$

Note that $m=2$ and $n=1$ yields
$$
2 \cdot 1^2 - 1 = ( 2 - 1 )^2
$$

We can now "generate" the next pairs...

$$
\big( m', n' \big) = \big( 3 \cdot 2^2 - 1^2 + 1, 2^2 + 1^2 \big)
= \big( 12 , 5 \big).
$$

$$
\big( m'', n'' \big) = \big( 3 \cdot 12^2 - 5^2 + 1, 12^2 + 5^2 \big)
= \big( 408 , 169 \big).
$$

$$
\big( m''', n''' \big) = \big( 3 \cdot 408^2 - 169^2 + 1, 408^2 + 169^2 \big)
= \big( 470832, 195025 \big).
$$

The number we are looking for are the numbers $n$, the first given by
$$
n = 1\\
n = 5\\
n = 169\\
n = 195025
$$

This are not all numbers, as the is a second method to generate pairs $(m',n')$.

I am still working on the second method.

---

The general method is given by

$$
2 x_n^2 - 1 = y_n^2,
$$

where both $x_n$ and $y_n$ are integers, then
$$
x_n = \frac{7 + 5 \sqrt{2}}{2 \sqrt{2}} \Big( 3 + 2 \sqrt{2} \Big)^{n-1}
-\frac{7 - 5 \sqrt{2}}{2 \sqrt{2}}   \Big( 3 - 2 \sqrt{2} \Big)^{n-1}.
$$

The results are
$$
\begin{array}{l|l}
n & x_n\\
\hline
0 & 1\\
1 & 5\\
2 & 29\\
3 & 169\\
4 & 985\\
5 & 5741\\
6 & 33461\\
7 & 195025\\
8 & 1136689\\
9 & 6625109\\
10 & 38613965
\end{array}
$$

(need to post how to derive it, but it is long)

---

The basic idea to derive it:

Given
$$
2 x_n^2 - 1 = y_n^2.
$$

Note that
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_{n+1} \\
y_{n+1}
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 2 \\
4 & 3
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_n \\
y_n
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_0 \\
y_0
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
1
\end{array}
\right).
$$

So
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_n \\
y_n
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 2 \\
4 & 3
\end{array}
\right)^n
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
1
\end{array}
\right).
$$

Let $\chi$ be the trace of the matrix and $\Delta$ the determinant,
then the eigenvalues are given by $\lambda_\pm = \chi/2 \pm \sqrt{\chi^2/4 - \Delta}$.

Then
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 2 \\
4 & 3
\end{array}
\right)^n
=
\frac{\lambda_+^n - \lambda_-^n}{\lambda_+ - \lambda_-}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 2 \\
4 & 3
\end{array}
\right)
-
\lambda_+ \lambda_-
\frac{\lambda_+^{n-1} - \lambda_-^{n-1}}{\lambda_+ - \lambda_-}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

From this follows that
$$
x_n =
5 \frac{\lambda_+^n - \lambda_-^n}{\lambda_+ - \lambda_-} -
\lambda_+ \lambda_-
\frac{\lambda_+^{n-1} - \lambda_-^{n-1}}{\lambda_+ - \lambda_-}
$$

and
$$
y_n =
7 \frac{\lambda_+^n - \lambda_-^n}{\lambda_+ - \lambda_-} -
\lambda_+ \lambda_-
\frac{\lambda_+^{n-1} - \lambda_-^{n-1}}{\lambda_+ - \lambda_-}.
$$

Working this out we get
$$
x_n = \frac{7 + 5 \sqrt{2}}{2 \sqrt{2}} \Big( 3 + 2 \sqrt{2} \Big)^{n-1}
-\frac{7 - 5 \sqrt{2}}{2 \sqrt{2}}   \Big( 3 - 2 \sqrt{2} \Big)^{n-1}.
$$

(I have written this post fast, so forgive me for some typos :)

Answer (score 3):

As Daniel Fischer has said, you end up with $w^2 - 2x^2 = -1$, which is a negative Pell equation. I asked a question very similar earlier. The fundamental and minimal solution is $(w_1, x_1) = (1, 1)$. The rest of the solutions can be solved as convergents of the continued fraction of $\sqrt{2}$. The next solutions are described by the recurrence equations $w_{k+1} = 3w_k + 4x_k,\ x_{k+1} = 2w_k + 3x_k$. This resolves to $x_k = 6x_{k-1} - x_{k-2}$, with $x_0 = 0$. More information [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1357031/122489).

Answer (score 3):

**Continued Fraction Approach**

Suppose $2q^2-1=p^2$. Then
$$
\left(\sqrt2-\frac pq\right)\left(\sqrt2+\frac pq\right)=\frac1{q^2}\tag{1}
$$
Thus,
$$
\left|\sqrt2-\frac pq\right|\lt\frac1{2q^2}\tag{2}
$$
The only rational approximations that are this good are [Continued Fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) approximations. The continued fraction for $\sqrt2$ is $(1;2,2,2,2,\dots)$. Using the table below, where each column below the line is the sum of the the number above that column times previous column plus the column preceding that:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
&&1&2&2&2&2&2&2\\\hline
0&1&1&3&7&17&41&99&239\\
1&0&1&2&5&12&29&70&169
\end{array}\tag{3}
$$
the first several convergents for this continued fraction are
$$
\color{#00A000}{\frac11},\frac32,\color{#00A000}{\frac75},\frac{17}{12},\color{#00A000}{\frac{41}{29}},\frac{99}{70},\color{#00A000}{\frac{239}{169}},\cdots\tag{4}
$$
Under- and over-estimates alternate, Thus, the green entries are under-estimates.

Since the numerators and denominators follow the recurrence
$$
(S^2-2S-1)a=0\tag{5}
$$
where $S$ is the shift operator $Sa_n=a_n+1$, and $(x^2-2x-1)(x^2+2x-1)=x^4-6x^2+1$, the numerators and denominators must also satisfy
$$
(S^4-6S^2+1)a=0\tag{6}
$$
Therefore, the recurrence for every other numerator and denominator is
$$
a_n=6a_{n-2}-a_{n-4}\tag{7}
$$

> Thus, if we start out with $a_1=1$ and $a_2=5$, then compute successive terms with
>   $$
> a_n=6a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}\tag{8}
> $$
>   we get all integers so that $8a_n^2-4=4(2a_n^2-1)$ is a square.

---

**Notes**
$(1)$: If $q\ne0$, this is equivalent to $2q^2-1=p^2$.
$(2)$: Since $p\ge q$, we actually have $\left|\sqrt2-\frac pq\right|\le\frac1{(1+\sqrt2)q^2}\lt\frac1{2q^2}$. The claim about rational approximations is Theorem $5.6$ from [this paper](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78279253/contfrac.pdf).
$(3)$: This table was generated as described in the preceding paragraph. It is simply using the Wallis Algorithm, in particular Corollary $2.2$, from [this paper](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78279253/contfrac.pdf).
$(4)$: This list simply collects the convergents from table $(3)$ and colors the under-estimates green.
$(5)$: This equation is an operator-based restatement of $a_n=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$.
$(6)$: Any sequence that satisfies the constraint in $(5)$ also satisfies this equation.
$(7)$: This is a restatement of $(6)$, which is a relation among every other element of the sequence. This gives us a recurrence on the numerators and denominators of the under-estimates.
$(8)$: Describe the sequence of denominators for the under-estimates.

Answer (score 2):

- According to [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001653)

> -$a(n) = 6a(n-1) - a(n-2)$ with $a(1)=1, a(2)=5.$

**developing it ..**

$a(3)=6a(2)-a(1)$ coeffecients of $6^n$ are: $1,-1$

$a(4)=6^2a(2)-6a(1)-a(2)$ coeffecients: $1,-1,-1$

$a(5)=6^3a(2)-6^2a(1)-6a(2)-6a(2)+a(1)$ coeffecients: $1,-1,-2,1$

$a(6)=6^4a(2)-6^3a(1)-3*6^2a(2)+2*6a(1)+a(2)$ coeffecients: $1,-1,-3,2,1$

in general:

$coeff(a(n))=\{coeff(a(n-1)),0,0\}-\{0,0,coeff(a(n-2))\}$

**binary analysis...**

$11100000000$

$00110000000$ $k=0$

---

$00111000000$ $k=1$

---

$00111000000$

$00001100000$ $k=2$

---

$00111000000$

$00001100000$

$00001110000$ $k=3$

---

$00111000000$

$00001100000$

$00001110000$

$00000011000$ $k=4$

---

$00111000000$

$00001100000$

$00001110000$

$00000011000$

$00000011100$ $k=5$

---

first bit:  1

second bit: 1

third bit:  2+k

fourth bit: 1+k

fifth bit:  1+2+3(k-2)

sixth bit:  1+2+2(k-3)

seventh bit:1+2+3(k-4)

eighth bit: 1+2+2(k-5)

general sequence of coeffecients is :$\{1,-1,-2-n,1+n,1+2+3(k-l),-1-2-2(k-l-1)..\},l<k$

---

### **final formula:**

- $a(3)=6a(2)-a(1)$
- $a(4)=6^2a(2)-6a(1)-a(2)$
- $a(4+(k=1))=1*6^3a(2)-1*6^2a(1)-2*6^1a(2)+1*6^0a(1)$
- $a(4+(k=2))=1*6^4a(2)-1*6^3a(1)-3*6^2a(2)+2*6^1a(1)-1a(2)$

...

> - $a(4+k)=1*6^{k+2}*a(2)-1*6^{k+1}*a(1)-(k+1)*6^{k}*a(2)+(k)*6^{k-1}*a(1)+(1+2+3(k-2))*6^{k-2}*a(2)-(1+2+3(k-3))*6^{k-3}*a(1)-...+(-1)^{2^{(l(l+1))mod4}}*((l+2>=k)+2*(l+1>=k)+(3-(lmod2))*(k-l))*a(lmod2+2)$ all values are non negative