# Solution to an indeterminate equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have an equation of the form $$Dx^2-2s.t.x+t^2=c^2$$ where $s$, $t$ and $x$ are positive integers and $c$ can be any positive and odd integer. Is there a method to recursively find the values of $x$ that satisfy this particular equation? Let us take the example of $D=13$, $s=3$ and $t=2$. Then the values of $x$ which form the solution space are $660$ and $78480$. Is there a way to find it without resorting to brute force calculations?

A rather special case of this would be to take $D=s^2+t^2$. I have this solution on this site,  [General method for determining if $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ is square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496083/general-method-for-determining-if-ax2-bx-c-is-square), but how do I proceed in this case of the residue being an odd square?

Comment: Any restrictions on $D$?

Comment: D should Just be positive. A rather special case of this would be to solve for $D=s^2+t^2$.